# Passing Route Parameters to Filters when Using RESTful Controllers

Tags: laravel, routes

I have searched around for long but nothing can quite fit my problem.
I am using RESTful controllers on my site. For some controller actions, some filters are needed and with this i do something like (i use the `beforeFilter()` function in the constructor):

```
<?php
    class PostController extends BaseController {

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->beforeFilter('auth',array('only'=>array('getCreate','postCreate','getEdit','postEdit','postAddComment')));
            $this->beforeFilter('csrf',array('only'=>array('postCreate','postEdit')));
        //  $this->beforeFilter('auth_post_edit', array('only'=>array('postEdit','getEdit')));
        }

        public function getIndex
        {

            $posts = Post::all();
            return View::make('home')->with('posts',$posts);
        }

        public function getCreate()
        {
            return View::make('posts.create');
        }
...
```

For the commented filter, however, it is meant to ensure that only the author of a post can edit the post, so i need to pass the `post_id` which is passed as a URI parameter, to the filter(or access it from the filter). 
Some link showed how i can access parameters from the filter using the `$route->getParameter('param')` in the filter, but the problem is that because i have not even named my parameters(they are named in the controller actions), i am not able to access them from the filter using the above method.
So, how can i access route parameters from within the filter, or/and how do i name route parameters in RESTful controllers(not in their actions)?

Comment: You could also try with Input::get('album_id') (or whatever parameter you have) in the filter.

Comment: @DimitrisKontoulis, but i thought the `Input::get()` is used when you are dealing with inputs from a form? (It is not working). I have just had to shelve the idea of RESTful controllers and decided to just do everything from `routes.php`

Comment: Or You can use the Request::segment() method then. It is In the  Illuminate\Http\Request class.

Answer (score 1):

You could use in your filter the Request::segment()

```
 Route::filter('foo', function()
{
    $param=Request::segment(2); //if the parameter is on the 2nd uri fregment.
    $post=Post::find($param);
    if ($post->author_id != Auth::user()->id)
    {
        return App::abort('404'); //or whatever
    }
});
```